# Syntaxhighlighter и другие не показывают вовсе

Tags: jquery, javascript

Проблема следующая, не syntaxhighlighter, не highlightjs не даже `<code>` не могут подсветить такие вещи как `<script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">`</script> например. Удивило меня и то, что `<code>` открестился от этого тупо исчезнув. Скажите пожалуйста, как же так получается и как с этим быть?

Использую:

```
<code><script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script></code>
```

или

```
<pre class="brush: js;">
<script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</pre>
```

Comment: `<pre>` прекращает чтение html. Пробовали `<code><pre> anything </pre></coe>`?

Comment: Да, перестаёт показывать вообще

Comment: Вот например на сайте http://arcticlab.ru/arcticmodal/#desc у них чётко всё выводится. Может проблема с редактором? Кто знает, каким пользуются они?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="style" href="../style/default.css" />
 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="imageload/js/ajaxupload.3.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/styles/default.min.css">
 <script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
Подключение всего.
Если даже строка и появляется, то без < скобочки у закрывающего </script> - script

Answer (score 1):

А может надо

```
<pre>
&lt;script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

А то иначе оно браузером воспринимается как теги и соответствующе обрабатываются

А если вы посмотрите пример из комментариев то увидите там как раз то о чём я говорил:

```
<pre><code class="javascript">var c = $('&lt;div class="b-modal" /&gt;');
c.html($('.b-text').html());
c.prepend('&lt;div class="b-modal_close arcticmodal-close"&gt;X&lt;/div&gt;');
$.arcticmodal({
    content: c
});</code></pre>
```

Comment: Он не отображает, только пустоту.

Comment: @Сергей Кашурин, а теперь больше смысла. Кто он, что за пустота? Космос? Может код приведёте?

Comment: Просто полоска темноватого цвета, как на тексте который подсвечен, только без текста... будто бы библиотека тупо подключается.

Comment: <pre><code class="javascript">&lt;script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</code></pre> пробую это, и тоже пустота.

Comment: @Сергей Кашурин, добавьте контекста пожалуйста? Желательно в вопрос.

Comment: Я подсвечиваю текст этим плагином
    <!-- Highlight -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.0/styles/default.min.css">
 <script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
В БД, через CKEDITOR я пишу текст, но это не суть важно, потому как увидев косяк я начал менять в MySql напрямую. Смысл в том, что текст, скажем подключения jQuery библиотеки с гугла не подсвечивается +скрипты ниже отрубаются...

Comment: Приведите куски кода страницы, подключения скриптов? Поверьте, проблема не в highlight.min.js.